# На то время / в то время

Tags: предлоги, семантика

В чём отличие:

> В то время цена была многократно выше рыночной.

от

> На то время цена была многократно выше рыночной.

При замене «в» на «на» сохраняется ли семантика в данном контексте? Если да, то полностью или частично?

Comment: На то время цена была выше, но в то время она упала. На то время = к тому времени (но без привязки ко времени)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Различие в предлогах указывает здесь на *разный контекст*. В первом случае (*в то время*) речь может идти о неопределенном по длительности временном **интервале** в прошлом (напр. время действия особого налога). Во втором - о конкретном **моменте** во времени, привязанном к какому-то *событию* (напр. начало действия экономических санкций); при этом можно предположить, что до и после этого цена существенно изменялась, а выражение "*на то время*" фиксирует состояние цен на *момент* упомянутого ранее события. Близкое значение имеет выражение "*к тому времени*", с той разницей, что акцентируются изменения до обозначенного момента во времени, в то время как последующие изменения игнорируются.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, отличие присутствует.

1. **В то время цена была многократно выше рыночной.**
   Здесь просто констатируется факт, что цены были высокими в рассматриваемом периоде.
2. **На то время цена была многократно выше рыночной.**
   Здесь же подразумевается своего рода “итог во времени,” что в результате определенного хода событий цены на тот момент *уже* были высокими.